# I wanted to remap the values of a dictionary into a data frame

Tags: python

I wanted to remap the values in a column in pandas Dataframe

```
title_dictionary = {"Capt": "Officer", "Col": "Officer"}
df["Title"] =  df['Title'].map('title_dictionary')
```

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Can some one please help me and let me know what mistake am I doing?

Comment: What is the expected DF?

Comment: Hello, can you add the expected result to your question?

Comment: The quotes around `title_dictionary` are making the dict a string. Remove the quotes to use the dict object.  Additionally, it’s often useful to create a new column which contains the mapping result, rather than overwriting the original column.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not really clear from your question what the desired result is, but try a list comprehension (I think this does what you want, although that’s guesswork).

```
df["Title"] =  [key for key in title_dictionary.keys()]
```

Comment: No, incorrect.  This is not creating a mapping as required.

Comment: Please explain what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should just pass your `title_dictionary` without quotes, like this:

```
df['Title'] =  df['Title'].map(title_dictionary)
```

DF initially:

```
   Title
0  Capt
1  Col
```

DF output after map operation:

```
     Title
0  Officer
1  Officer
```